# Why does Solr cloud separate write and read operations?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Solr cloud separates the writes (making index) and reads (searching). All of the writes will go to leader shards, whereas all of the reads will go to replicate shards, why does solr design this pattern please? Can the read operation go into leaders as well (is it really that all the reads will go to replicates?)

Answer (score 1):

All writes go to the leader then the leader forwards the update request to the replicas in the same transaction. Writes go to the leader so documents can be merged with the latest version and it also makes orchestration a bit simpler. As for reads, queries are load balanced across all nodes (leaders + replicas).

Comment: thank you so much sdavids, Could you please give me more detailed explanation about "so documents can be merged with the latest version and it also makes orchestration a bit simpler". -Jack

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Read operation can go to leader as well. You can check the transaction log of the leader to confirm the read operation severed by the leader as well.